# Сортировка абсолютных значений на Питоне

Tags: python, сортировка, числа, числовые-последовательности

Задана последовательность из n целых чисел. Ваша задача упорядочить числа по возрастанию их абсолютных значений. Если у двух чисел одинаковое абсолютное значение, но разные знаки, то первым должно идти отрицательное число.

Input

```
5
8 -9 3 3 -3
```

Output

```
-3 3 3 8 -9
```

Comment: и на каком языке это делать? для разных языков могут быть разные подходы

Comment: @makekaper,  в следующий раз приложите, пожалуйста Вашу попытку решить задачу или постарайтесь как можно чётче описать с чем именно у Вас возникли трудности. Здесь принято помогать и объяснять, но не принято делать чужую работу. Особенно остро стоит вопрос у учебными заданиями. То что `Zhihar`,  ответил на Ваш вопрос удача для Вас и ему еще могут за это насувать минусов в ответ.

Comment: справка: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

код:

```
max_value = max(abs(min(arr)), abs(max(arr)))
arr.sort(key=lambda i: abs(i) * max_value - (i < 0))
```

с питоном сложнее, чем с остальными языками, поскольку там с сортировкой похуже, поэтому можно применить такой ход

1. получать абсолютное значение сортируемого элемента
2. умножать его на абсолютное значение максимального элемента

это гарантирует, что два отличных элемента теперь будут отделены некоторой дельтой больше 1

3. вычитать в случае отрицательного значения элемента из результата 2) `1`

это гарантирует, что элемент с одинаковым абсолютным значением, но отрицательным знаком будет отсортирован левее, чем элемент с положительным знаком

P.S.

если сортируются не целые числа, а числа с плавающей запятой, то подход будет примерно тот же, только надо находить не максимальное значение, а минимальную дельту между элементами и дальше использовать схожий подход

Comment: он был указан в названии вопроса(язык). добавил метку

Comment: ок, тогда убрал лишнее :)

Comment: да, не подумал, но главное что подход тот же

Comment: да, скорректировал код, так что ваш подход лучше

Comment: что кинуть в ответ?

Answer (score 4):

Питон сравнивает списки лексикографически: если первые элементы не равны, то они определяют порядок, иначе вторые элементы и так до конца обоих списков. Воспользуемся этим, сравним пары вида `(abs(v), v)`. Первый элемент пары отвечает за сортировку по абсолютной величине, второй упорядочивает числа одинаковые по абсолютной величине но разные по знаку:

```
a.sort(key=lambda v: (abs(v), v))
```

Тест:

```
@>>> a = [3, -9, 8, 0, -4, 2, -1, -5, -3, 6, 9, 1, 7, 0, -8, -2, 5, -7, 4, -6]
@>>> a.sort(key=lambda v: (abs(v), v))
@>>> a
[0, 0, -1, 1, -2, 2, -3, 3, -4, 4, -5, 5, -6, 6, -7, 7, -8, 8, -9, 9]
```

Comment: Опередили )  Почему-то всё время все забывают, что в питоне ключом сортировки может быть кортеж )