# Задача на строки питон

Tags: python, строки

> Как известно, Винни-Пуха очень расстраивают длинные слова. У него есть одно такое слово и он очень хочет его сократить. Винни-Пух решил, что если он выбросит из слова все вхождения некоторой одной буквы, то смысл слова не очень изменится, но слово станет короче
>
> Ваша задача — найти какое самое короткое слово сможет получить Винни-Пух. Если вариантов ответа несколько, то можно вывести любой.

Input

```
oboronosposobnost
brnspsbnst
```

Output

```
abbba
aa
```

я так понял можно использовать метод строки count и соответсвенно удалить, убрать.

Comment: Посчитать вхождения для каждой буквы и удалить то, которая больше всего места занимает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = 'oboronosposobnost'
s = s.replace(max(s, key=s.count), '')
print(s)
```

Comment: Слово длинной в 10000 символов огорчит не только медвежёнка но и этот квадратичный алгоритм.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, я немного упростил код из другого ответа, на эффективность не претендую.

Comment: Да, ваш код проще и более "питонический".

Answer (score 4):

Посчитать вхождения для каждой буквы и удалить ту, которая больше всего места занимает.

```
s = 'oboronosposobnost'
s.replace(max([s.count(x), x] for x in s)[1], '')
```

Comment: `s = 'oboronosposobnost'                                                                  
s = s.replace(max([s.count(x), x] for x in s)[1], '')`

Comment: @Danis, хм, не помню как там max считает, если список

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1218557/400096

Comment: @Danis, вспомнил, спасибо

Comment: Слово длинной в 10000 символов огорчит не только медвежёнка но и этот квадратичный алгоритм.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, интересно, а какая сложность в метода `.count()`? Если бы так, то можно было бы по алфавиту пройтись..

Comment: Линейная, конечно.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, сейчас переделаю. А за O(n) в принципе логично)) Но мало ли.

Comment: Алфавит перебирать не надо. Алфавиты бывают большие.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, *Согласно Книге рекордов Гиннесса, больше всего букв — 74 — содержится в алфавите кхмерского языка*

Comment: :). Мишка может читать любые тексты в Юникоде. Это большой алфавит.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно найти самую популярную букву. `collection.Counter(word)` возвращает словарь с популярностью всех букв в слове. Извлекаем из него всё в виде пар. Пары переворачиваем вот так: `(популярность, буква)`. Из таких пар можно выбрать максимальную. `word.replace(буква, '')` удаляет её. Работает за линейное время.

```
import collections


def help_bear(word):
    _, most_popular = max((n, c) for c, n in collections.Counter(word).items())
    return word.replace(most_popular, '')


print(help_bear('abca'))
print(help_bear('a' * 10000 + 'b' + 'a' * 10000))
```